# Can't access assets.open() in OnBindBiewHolder in Kotlin. Trying to load an image from my assets folder into certain rows

Tags: image, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
val padder = holder?.view?.padImage
val inputStream = assets.open("greenface.jpg")
val drawableNew = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null)
padder.setImageDrawable(drawableNew)
```

It throws an error saying unresolved reference open. This worked perfectly fine in my Main activity class

Comment: can you add the error stacktrace?

Comment: @Pievis Sorry, it shows the error before I even run the code that open is an unresolved reference, it appears that I can't access assets at all in the adapter, is that normal?

Comment: Provide activity context to your Adapter and use that passed context to load assets.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Thanks! You saved me, sorry I am new to Kotlin, switching over from Swift so many things are magical to me still.

Comment: If the assets were only working in Activity, then the only natural explanation would be that it needs a `Context` to run. Also, don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Taseer,

In main activity I passed the context of the activity to the adapter:

```
recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(Model, this)
```

In my adapter class I added the context argument:

```
class MainAdapter(val boulderProblems: List<BoulderProblems>, var context: 
Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {
```

And I adjusted my assets code to this:

```
val padder = holder?.view?.padImage
val inputStream = this.context.assets.open("greenface.jpg")
val drawableNew = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null)
padder.setImageDrawable(drawableNew)
```

Comment: Also, if you look at the first line of code, you are using `?` safe access, if by any means, the holder or the view results in `null`, it will set null to the `padder`. You might want to use a scoping function to give you whole code one scope. Example: `holder?.view?.let {  it.setImageDrawable( )  }`

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Thanks, the whole app runs off of static data stored on the phone, so there shouldn't be any issues with running into null. It's a reference app.